# Show live current elapsed time of a youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I know how to get the current elapsed time of a youtube video using...

```
player.getCurrentTime()
```

But I need a way to show this as updating text inside an element so I can display the current time of the youtube video counting while the video is playing. What's the correct way to do this preferably using jquery?

Comment: You could set a timeout and call `getCurrentTime` repeatedly.

Comment: Is doing this going to cause an issue with youtube if I'm doing this alot from one site?

Comment: IIUC the player is running locally, so the server won't mind.

Comment: Can you show how to do it in an answer please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the player doesn't offer a callback when the seconds roll over, you could still poll the current time. Choosing the correct polling frequency is a performance trade-off, but you don't really need to crank it up:

```
setInterval(function(){
   display.innerText = player.getCurrentTime();
},100); //polling frequency in miliseconds
```

jQuery does not really simplify the waiting but you can use it for DOM manipulation:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $display.text(player.getCurrentTime());
},100); //polling frequency in miliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code playground example that should help:

https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polling_the_player

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.